# How to automatically allocate the rest of free space to partition?

Tags: linux, partition, foreman

I have a question related to the configuration of a partition-table in "Foreman". As you can see in the screenshot below, I allocate 200 GB of free space to the /-Directory.

[image]

**The problem: how can I allocate the rest of free space to this partition?** Your answer would really help me out... I'm looking forward!

Thanks and best regards,

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `--grow` and `--maxsize`

```
logvol / --size=1 --grow --name=lv_root --vgname=vg00
```

or `--percent`

```
logvol / --percent=100 --name=lv_root --vgname=vg00
```

Option `--percent` can not be used together with the `--size` and `--grow` options.

Comment: Man you really helped me out! Thanks bro!